# Will Ubuntu Phone support Java?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm a Java developer and I was so excited when I heard that Ubuntu is going mobile...

But will it support a Java Runtime Environment like Ubuntu Desktop and Windows 8 Pro?

A lot of enterprise applications are running with Swing graphical toolkit, and its successor JavaFX2 offers some enhanced features for the Java world.

Will Canonical close their platform from other languages and runtimes in order to promote Canonical's solution ( Qt/QML/C++ based)?

Answer (score 2):

Currently canonical do not have any plan to officially support new language in ubuntu touch . But since java have linux arm version , you can install it. But none of currently existing java gui toolkits currently support MIR display server.
So don't expect gui apps with java atleast for now

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ubuntu website](http://ubuntu.com/phone):

> With all-native core apps and **no** Java overhead, Ubuntu runs well on
>   entry-level smartphones – yet it uses the same drivers as Android. So
>   now it’s easy to bring a better experience to customers all over the
>   world.

So apparently, **no** seems to be the answer.

Comment: That link leads to the homepage of the Ubuntu website. Can you provide the exact link to the page where that text can be found, please?

Comment: -1 , because the quote simply says 'java layer as in the case of android is not present in ubuntu ' it does not mean that java is not supported